# Variadic template with SFINAE

Tags: c++, variadic-templates, sfinae

```
template<class T> struct is_vector : public std::false_type {};

template<class T, class Alloc>
struct is_vector<std::vector<T, Alloc>> : public std::true_type {};

template<typename T>
template<typename... Ys, typename = typename std::enable_if<is_vector<std::decay_t<Ys...>>::value>::type>
void A<T>::function(Ys &&... y){}
```

For one vector work fine (version without variadic template), but if I try do for variadic template... it doesn't work, how can I make well SFINAE for variadic template. Someone can explain me why this doesn't work with variadic template and what I must improve.

Comment: You probably meant `std::decay_t<Ys>...`, but even if you fix that it will fail because `is_vector` is not variadic.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot check if the unexpaned pack is a vector.  You have to check for each element in the pack.  Your usage of `std::decay_t` indicates that you use C++17, so I assume you can use the fold expression.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <type_traits>
#include <vector>

template<class T> struct is_vector : public std::false_type {};

template<class T, class Alloc>
struct is_vector<std::vector<T, Alloc>> : public std::true_type {};

template<typename... Ys, typename = typename std::enable_if< (... && is_vector< std::decay_t<Ys> >::value) >::type >
void function(Ys&&...) { std::cout << __PRETTY_FUNCTION__ << '\n'; }

struct A {};

int main()
{
  std::vector<int> vi;
  std::vector<double> vd;
  std::vector<A> va;
  function(vi, vd, va);
}
```

Before C++17 you need a little helper struct which I call `all`.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <type_traits>
#include <vector>

template < bool... > struct all;
template < > struct all<> : std::true_type {};
template < bool B, bool... Rest > struct all<B,Rest...>
{
  constexpr static bool value = B && all<Rest...>::value;
};

template<class T> struct is_vector : public std::false_type {};

template<class T, class Alloc>
struct is_vector<std::vector<T, Alloc>> : public std::true_type {};

template<typename... Ys, typename = typename std::enable_if< all< is_vector< std::decay_t<Ys> >::value... >::value >::type >
void function(Ys&&...) { std::cout << __PRETTY_FUNCTION__ << '\n'; }

struct A {};

int main()
{
  std::vector<int> vi;
  std::vector<double> vd;
  std::vector<A> va;
  function(vi, vd, va);
}
```

Comment: thanks, now i understand solution before C++17, earlier i see this, but i had problem with understand.